# VBA: DLL error while opening specific module

Tags: vba, excel

My excel workbook is popping up with DLL error message when I try to open few of the modules. Where the code inside those module works perfectly...( I have one button which execute those code) Any idea what will be the reason or how to solve this problem ?? Because I have to make few changes on those code

[image: img]

Thank you

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your `Tools -> References`

Comment: Maybe this helps https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2249320/unable-to-add-refedit-control-to-vba-userform

Comment: (Off-topic:  Why did you delete [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202114/6535336) you posted a little while ago - I was hoping to be able to upvote it after you added the comment in.  If you like, undelete it and I will add the comment in for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Office 64-bit or alternative installations, then the DLL could be located elsewhere.

Search your system for the file:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. Type `REFEDIT.DLL` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   For example, mine is located at:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\REFEDIT.DLL`

Once you locate the file:

3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> copy the entire path
4. In Excel's VBA Editor, go `Tools` → `References`
5. **Un-check** the `MISSING:` reference
6. Click `Browse...`
7. <kbd>CTR L</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> paste in the correct path and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Scroll to find `REFEDIT.DLL` and double-click it,  Click `OK`

The issue should be resolved.