# VBA: How can I limit a 'For Each' function

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a macro that checks the matching values from column A and row 2 in sheet2. Based on each value in the range B3 to C6 (dynamic field may get changed (there is maximum 7 location and below that 5 roles, may appears here ) in sheet1.

Problem with my code is that my loop **"j"** is not working as expected... It will result in executing the code 8 to 16 times in per below scenario (where I am expected it to run only 4 times)

```
Sub GetRowNum()

Dim rLoc 
Dim rRol 
Dim LocSrch1 
Dim RolSrch1 
Dim disRangeLoc As Range 
Dim disRangeRol As Range 
Dim i 
Dim j 
Dim shtA As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long 
Dim lCol As Long 
Dim lInter As Variant 
Dim Table As Range

Set shtA = Sheets ("Sheet1") 'storing the sheets... 
Set shtB = Sheets ("Sheet2")

shtA.Activate 

rLoc = shtA.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row 
rRol = shtA.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row 'the last row of the list 


LocSrch1 = 2 'column A... changed if you need 
Set disRangeLoc = Range(Cells(3, LocSrch1), Cells(rLoc, LocSrch1)) 'here need to change the 2 for 
'1 if you do not want headers

RolSrch1 = 3 'column A... changed if you need 
Set disRangeRol = Range(Cells(3, RolSrch1), Cells(rRol, RolSrch1))


For Each i In disRangeLoc 'for each item inside the list of prod going to discount 
For Each j In disRangeRol 
MsgBox i 
MsgBox j 
shtB.Activate

Set Table = shtB.Range("A1:H7")

On Error Resume Next 
lRow = shtB.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(j, Range("A:A"), 0) 
On Error GoTo 0

If lRow > 0 Then 
End If

On Error Resume Next 
lCol = shtB.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, Range("2:2"), 0) 
On Error GoTo 0

If lRow > 0 Then 
End If

On Error Resume Next 
lInter = Application.WorksheetFunction(lCol, lRow).Value 
On Error GoTo 0

If lRow > 0 Then

MsgBox Table.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value

End If

On Error GoTo 0 
Next j 
Next i


End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

My final target is to find the revenue under D7 as shown in image1 (sheet1) and this code is 1st step towards it... If someone had a better suggestion to calculate in such a simple way, kindly guide me.

Someone, please help me to correct my code... And I hope u understand my requirement... Else please ask, I will try to explain better

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use `Exit For`. Hope this will do your trick.

Comment: Also please remove the `ON Error Resume Next` and `ON error goto`

Comment: You are executing the `For Each j` loop 4 times for each of the 4 iterations of the `For Each i` loop.  That makes 16 iterations in total.  Are you sure you want a `For Each j` loop, or did you just want to say `Set j = i.Offset(0, 1)`?

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K it worked :)

Comment: @YowE3K will you tell me how to feed these each value's (From Table.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value) into an active cell

Comment: To put something into a cell (cell B5 for instance), you can say `shtA.Cells(5, 2).Value = whatever_it_is_you_want_to_store`, or `shtA.Cells(5, "B").Value = ....`, or `shtA.Range("B5").Value = ....`, and several other ways.  I suspect the "whatever_it_is_you_want_to_store" in your case will be a variable containing the results of the calculations of what you originally had as a formula.

Comment: thanks @YowE3K  but not in that way, here my code will generate 4 different values and I want all of them to feed into the same column, if I use above query it will replace old values each time the Each loop runs

Comment: to get the values in one specific cell, just check the code, i just updated it

Comment: @user9184557 and you should always indent your code. It makes it easier to read and find mistakes.

Comment: I thought you were trying to create a replacement for your "revenue" formula.  So I expected you wouldn't be storing the 4 values into your column, you would have a variable (perhaps `Revenue`) and in your loop you would be saying `Revenue = Revenue + I.Offset(0, 2).Value * Table.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value` and after your loop you would be saying something like `shtA.Cells(RLoc + 1, "D").Value = Revenue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `For Each j In disRangeRol` then it will take each value in the range you already defined. if you keep `Set J = I.Offset(0, 1)` then it will consider and check the value in **'i'** if true it will take the value just right to it and won't go for Each values in disRangeRol, Try below code

```
Sub GetRowNum() 'find the value from Sheet2 if Location and Role matches

    Dim rLoc
    Dim rRol
    Dim LocSrch1
    Dim RolSrch1
    Dim disRangeLoc As Range
    Dim disRangeRol As Range
    Dim I
    Dim J
    Dim shtA As Worksheet
    Dim shtB As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lInter As Variant
Dim Table As Range

    Set shtA = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtB = Sheets("Sheet2")

    shtA.Activate

    rLoc = shtA.Range("B2").End(xlDown).row
    rRol = shtA.Range("C2").End(xlDown).row 'the last row of the list
                                    'with the discounted prods
                                    'If you do not want headers,
                                    'use A1 here


    LocSrch1 = 2 'column B... changed if you need
    Set disRangeLoc = Range(Cells(3, LocSrch1), Cells(rLoc, LocSrch1))  'here need to change the 2 for
                                                   '1 if you do not want headers

    RolSrch1 = 3 'column A... changed if you need
    Set disRangeRol = Range(Cells(3, RolSrch1), Cells(rRol, RolSrch1))


    For Each I In disRangeLoc 'for each item inside the list of prod going to discount
  Set J = I.Offset(0, 1) 'it will check the value in i if yes it will take the value just right to it

  shtB.Activate

Set Table = shtB.Range("A1:H7")

On Error Resume Next
    lRow = shtB.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(J, Range("A:A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lRow > 0 Then
    End If

On Error Resume Next
    lCol = shtB.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(I, Range("2:2"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lRow > 0 Then
    End If

On Error Resume Next
    lInter = Application.WorksheetFunction(lCol, lRow).Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lRow > 0 Then

'MsgBox I
'MsgBox J
MsgBox Table.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
RevValue = Table.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value 'it will set the values each time the loop run
    End If

        On Error GoTo 0

shtA.Activate ' help to make sure you feed the date in right sheet, else data will get feed to Sheet2

   ActiveCell.Value = RevValue & "," & ActiveCell.Value 'this will feed the date into the field using a comma separation 

    Next I

    shtA.Activate

End Sub
```

Updated the code to feed the data into specific column as well